# AngularJS UI Router : Loading Sibling Views on Demand

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been searching how to implement sibling views on demand. What I have achieved so far is loading them together. Below is the sample which i am working on.
When clicked on any **item** on the left, the right hand ui-view in blue is loaded, which has contains details of the item and also two named views. **Item Configuration** and **Item Price** are two anchor tags which when clicked will display the respective view.

I hope the description is helpful and if someone can provide a solution that would be helpful.

[image]

**View is written for the red border as follows** (HTCOne.cshtml)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5 ">
    <h1>Meet HTC One M8</h1>
</div>

<div class="col-md-5 ">
    <a ui-sref="SmartPhone.HTCOne.Config">See Configuration</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <a ui-sref="SmartPhone.HTCOne.Price">Price Range</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 ">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/HTCM8.JPG" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 ">
        <div ui-view="Config" autoscroll=" false"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <div ui-view="Price" autoscroll="false"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UI-router code**

```
 .state('SmartPhone.HTCOne', {
     url: '/HTCOne',
     templateUrl: '/home/HTCOne'
 })
 .state('SmartPhone.HTCOne.Price', {
     views: {
         'Price': {
             template: '<B>Ranges form $ - $</B>'
         },
         'Config': {
             templateUrl: '/home/HTCOneConfig'
         }
     }
 })
```

**Another version of UI-Router** - If I you use two different states for the two named views, I get only one view displayed at a time , like behaving mutually exculsive way

```
     .state('SmartPhone.HTCOne', {
         url: '/HTCOne',
         templateUrl: '/home/HTCOne'
     })
     .state('SmartPhone.HTCOne.Price', {
         views: {
             'Price': {
                 template: '<B>Ranges form $ - $</B>'
             }
         }
     })

 .state('SmartPhone.HTCOne.Config', {
     views: {

         'Config': {
             templateUrl: '/home/HTCOneConfig'
         }
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

UI router is essentially a state machine. 
You can only be in one state at any particular time(with exception of parent states which are active when children states are active).

In your situation dont you want both price and config visible at some point? If thats the case, using states is not appropriate. You should use ng-includes instead.

Update: 
Did you actually place the named ui-views where your black boxes are for "Some Configuration" and for "Item Price", i.e.

```
<div ui-view="Price"></div>
<div ui-view="Config"></div>
```

Comment: Purpose is to show the price and config at different times and on select a specific anchor tag

Comment: see my update, did you actually place ui-views in there?

Comment: the code which showed the ui-view was not rendered. see the update

Comment: templateUrl: '/home/HTCOne' doesnt seem to be correct. is /home/HTCOne an html file? if so can you show its contents?